# expectation and variance problem

Tags: probability

$n$ married couples (a total of 2n people) are randomly arranged in a line. Let $X$ be
the number of married couples that are standing next to each other. Compute the expectation
and variance of X

How can we solve this?
Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Write $X$ as a sum of simpler variables and use the linearity of expectation and the formula for the variance of a sum:

For $i=1,\ldots,n$ define 
$$X_i=\cases{1, & if the $i$'th wife stands next to her husband \cr 0,& otherwise.} $$
 Then $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Towards finding the expectation of $X$:

Note $\Bbb E(X_i)=\Bbb E(X_j)$ for all $i$, $j$.   We then have 
$$\Bbb E(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \Bbb E(X_i) =n\Bbb E(X_1).$$

Towards finding the variance of $X$:

Use the formula (note the $X_i$ are not independent)
$$ \sigma^2(X)  = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sigma^2_{X_i} +   2\sum\limits_{i< j} {\rm Cov}(X_i,X_j)=n \sigma^2_{X_1} +n(n-1){\rm Cov}(X_1,X_2).$$

To compute $ {\rm Cov}(X_1,X_2)$, use the identity 
$$ {\rm Cov}(X,Y)= \Bbb E(XY)-\mu_X\mu_ Y.$$ 
Towards finding $\Bbb E(X_1X_2)$, note that $X_1X_2$ is a Bernouili variable; so, $$\Bbb E(X_1X_2)=P[X_1X_2=1]=P[X_1=1,X_2=2]=P[X_1=1]\cdot P[X_2=1|X_1=1].$$

I'll leave it to you to compute the relevant quantities.

Comment: How can I calculate P[x1 x2] and P[x1]?

Comment: hey, is E[x1] = 1/n and E[x1 x2] = 2/ 2n-1?

Comment: @paulmarcus $\Bbb E(X_1)=P[X_1=1]=1/n$, but $\Bbb E[X_iX_2]=2/(n(2n-1))$, I think. To find $P[X_1=1]$, condition on whether the couple occupies a place at the end of the line or not. To find $P[X_2=1 | X_1=1]$, you could condition on which two places the first couple occupy.

Comment: @David Mitra I'm also working on this problem, and I have some questions about caculating $E(X)$. The $n$ married couples are arranged in a **line**. If the wife seats in one of the middle seat, then the husband can seats in one of the two seats beside the wife, the probability is $\frac{2}{n-1}$. But if the wife seats in one of the end seat, then the husband only has one choice, which is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Should we treat the 2 cases separately when calculating $E(X)$??

Comment: @user59036 Yes. Your numbers seem a bit off. Note $\Bbb E(X_1)=P[X_1=1]$. There are four ways the couple can sit together at an end. There are $2\cdot(2n-3)$ ways they can sit together in the middle. Then $P[X=1]=(4+2(2n-3))/(2n(2n-1))$. Also, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299287/marriage-probability-problem).

Comment: @user59036 Without counting, the probability they sit together with the wife at an end is $(2/(2n))\cdot(1/(2n-1))$. (Note there are $2n$ seats.)